# Iterate through struct by variable name

Tags: c++, reflection, iterator, iteration, c-preprocessor

UPDATE: 6 months later, and I just came across this answer: [Is it legal to index into a struct?: Answer by Slava](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40590471/2066079) . I think this is a MUCH better solution than any of the ones provided here, as there is absolutely no undefined behavior. Hopefully this helps the next person, since it is already too late for me to implement.

---

**Before you comment telling me to use an array or vector, or any form of container instead, it is a hard truth that I cannot. I know, this would be solved with an array, and any solution otherwise is pretty "hacky". I would love to use a container, but I absolutely cannot.**

I am a mid-level developer at a very large corporation, and we are using a company-wide library for sending data over ethernet. There are various reasons for why it cannot support arrays/vectors, and instead, uses structs of POD (Plain Old Data - chars, floats, ints, bools). I start with an array of floats that I must use to fill a struct with the same number of floats. Since the purpose of this library is to send messages over ethernet, I only need to do the iteration twice - once on the send and one on the receive. All other times, this data is stored as an array. I know - I should be serializing the arrays and sending them as is, but I repeat - I absolutely cannot.

I have a `float[1024]`, and must iterate through the array and fill the following struct:

```
struct pseudovector
{
    float data1;
    float data2;
    float data3;
    ...
    float data1024;
}
```

I am already generating this struct with [BOOST_PP_REPEAT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18441431/boost-pp-repeat-with-array) and [BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH_I](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18483572/how-can-i-use-a-macro-for-collecting-variable-names/18483867#18483867) so that I do not have to write out all 1024 floats, and it increases maintainability/extensibility.

In the same fashion, I have tried iterating through the struct via pre-compiler `##` concatination (https://stackoverflow.com/a/29020943/2066079), but as this is done at pre-compiler time, it cannot be used for run-time getting/setting.

I have looked at implementing reflection such as [How can I add reflection to a C++ application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41453/how-can-i-add-reflection-to-a-c-application) and [Ponder Library](https://github.com/billyquith/ponder), but both approaches requires you to explicitly write out each item that can be reflected upon. In that case, I might as well just create a `std::map<string, float>` and iterate in a for loop via string/integer concatenation:

```
for(i=0;i<1024;i++)
{
    array[i] = map.get(std::string("data")+(i+1))
}
```

Can anyone recommend a cleaner solution that does not require me to write out in excess of 1024 lines of code? Your help is appreciated!

**Again, I repeat - I absolutely cannot use an array/vector of any sort.**

Comment: this seems like anti-pattern. could you wrap this struct in a union? `union wrapper { float arr[1024]; pseudovector vec; };`

Comment: Why not just 
`float[1024] fa; pseudovector pv; memcpy(fa,&pv, sizeof(pv));` ?

Comment: @c-smile Because this is undefined behavior

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This may well be easier than you expect. First, some caveats:

1. Arrays are guaranteed, by the standard, to be contiguous; that is, there's no padding inserted between them, and the array itself is aligned with the alignment requirements of the element type.
2. Structs have no such restrictions; they can be subject to arbitrary padding. However, a given implementation (at a given version) will do this the same way in all translation units (otherwise, how else could the same structure definition be used to pass data across translation units?). The usual way this is done is fairly sane, especially when the struct contains *only* members of a single type. For such a struct, the alignment *usually* matches the largest alignment of the members, and there's *usually* no padding because all members have the same alignment.

In your case, your array of 1024 floats and your struct with 1024 float members *almost certainly* have exactly the same memory layout. This is *absolutely not guaranteed by the standard*, but your compiler may document its struct layout rules, and you can always assert the sizes and alignments match in your unit tests (you do have unit tests, right?)

Given those caveats, you will *almost certainly* be able to simply `reinterpret_cast` (or `memcpy`) between the two.

Answer (score 3):

You can use type punning to treat the structure as an array.

```
float array[1024] = { ... };
pseudovector pv1;
float *f = static_cast<float*>(static_cast<void*>(&pv1));
for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++) {
    f[i] = array[i];
}
```

Comment: As long as you're OK with undefined behaviour.

Comment: Since he's sending the structure over Ethernet, he's obviously OK with that. The code to write it almost certainly makes the same assumption of contiguous data.

Comment: Nice, thanks! And this works because all the items in the struct are floats, right? If there were of mixed types (i.e. header information in each struct) this could not be used?

Comment: [`static_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast) [will not perform that conversion](http://ideone.com/hu9l49) (without [going via `void*`](http://ideone.com/7LUMpo)).

Comment: @Andrew I admit I'm not up to speed on all the C++ cast operators; what's the right one for this?

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` is the only one that'll cast between unrelated types. Or `static_cast<float*>(static_cast<void*>(&pv1));` which goes via `void*`. Both are technically UB but if you know the memory layout is identical you should be able to get away with it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use preprocessor metaprogramming to create your array.  You could do something like:

```
#define ACCESSOR(z, n, type) &type::data ## n

auto arr[] = {
    BOOST_PP_ENUM(1000, ACCESSOR, pseudovector)
};
```

Will need to adjust ACCESSOR most likely.  It might not be legal to use `auto` here either.

Then you do:

```
auto val = (pv1.*arr)[4];
```

etc...

No UB needed.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Boost.Hana](http://www.boost.org/libs/hana/), if you can compile with recent versions of Clang or GCC (afaik, the only compilers supported.)

Allow me to quote the section [Introspection](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/hana/doc/html/index.html#tutorial-introspection) from the tutorial:

> Static introspection, as we will discuss it here, is the ability of a
>   program to examine the type of an object at compile-time. In other
>   words, it is a programmatic interface to interact with types at
>   compile-time. For example, have you ever wanted to check whether some
>   unknown type has a member named foo? Or perhaps at some point you have
>   needed to iterate on the members of a struct?

For [introspecting user-defined types](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/hana/doc/html/index.html#tutorial-introspection-adapting) you do have to define the struct with Hana, but this is not much different than defining a struct otherwise:

```
struct pseudovector {
   BOOST_HANA_DEFINE_STRUCT(pseudovector,
    (float, data1),
    (float, data2),
    …
  );
};
```

And you should easily be able to modify whatever macros you have to generate your current struct, to generate this one instead.

This adds a nested struct to `pseudovector`, which consists only of a static member function. It does not affect POD-ness, size, or data layout.

Then you can iterate through it as in this example:

```
pseudovector pv;

hana::for_each(pv, [](auto pair) {
  std::cout << hana::to<char const*>(hana::first(pair)) << ": "
            << hana::second(pair) << std::endl;
});
```

Here, `pair`'s members are a hana compile-time string (the member name) and the value. If you'd rather have your lambda take two arguments (the name and the value), use `hana::fuse`:

```
hana::for_each(pv, hana::fuse([](auto name, auto member) {
  std::cout << hana::to<char const*>(name) << ": " << member << std::endl;
}));
```

Comment: @Andrew: done. FWIW, at the time I was thinking in terms of demonstrating that Hana does what's desired, by quoting the docs